# How to create a new Angular 10 app locally while using Angular 16 globally?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have installed Angular 16 globally on my machine. I need to create a new angular 10 app locally. I have 2 node versions for different Angular CLI.

1. I created a new directory called Angular-10
2. installed Angular 10 locally.

**But whenever I command in cmd  npx ng new myapp, it says the app cannot install, Access is denied.**

What is the solution?

Comment: Why would you want to create a v10 version today ??

Comment: because I've got to work on Angular 10 old project.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Angular project using this specific version. Run the following command:

```
npx -p @angular/cli@10 ng new project-name
```

Comment: Hi, this is the error I am getting now 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-06T08_21_05_974Z-debug-0.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Comment: You should try accessing the directory of the recently created project and run the command 'sudo npm i'

Comment: This is what I did.

Documents\Angular Project\Angular-10>npx -p @angular/cli@10 ng new myapp.

then the error occurs

Comment: After executing that command, do you see the 'myapp' directory created? If the directory has been successfully created, you can navigate to the 'myapp' directory and run the command 'sudo npm i'.

Comment: it failed to create the project and shows lots of errors. By the way, my machine is running on node 18 while installing angular 10.  When I switch to Node 12 via NVM and try to create the project, it says "Access is denied, this app cannot install"